# Use string to refer to an array name in vba

Tags: arrays, vba, powerpoint

I have Powerpoint presentation. On each slide I have 8 shapes with text space. They can contain text representing group which has sth related to content/data update and so on.
I have following arrays which contain users for those responsibility area:

```
GEN = Array("username_01","username_02","username_03",..."username_xx")
POL = Array("username_01","username_02","username_03",..."username_xx")
B2B = Array("username_01","username_02","username_03",..."username_xx")
RUS = Array("username_01","username_02","username_03",..."username_xx")
```

And this function which is checking if user is in array

```
   Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
   IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
   End Function
```

My problem is that when I want to use the function it works only if I will give the Array name as below:

```
auser = Environ("UserName")
IsInArray(auser,GEN) 'it will give me answer if the user is in array
```

I want to get shape text:

```
res_group_txt = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(shape_owner).TextEffect.Text
```

And put it somehow in a function so it will not return an error

```
auser = Environ("UserName")
IsInArray(auser,res_group_txt)
```

I have tried to change variables and look through all topics but I have not found answer :(

Help pls :)

BR Misza

Comment: Have you tried changing the parameters of the filter function to CompareMethod.Text or CompareMethod.binary?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Dictionary object to map the text to the array...

```
Dim oDic As Object
Dim GEN As Variant
Dim POL As Variant
Dim B2B As Variant
Dim RUS As Variant

GEN = Array("username_01", "username_02", "username_03")
POL = Array("username_01", "username_02", "username_03")
B2B = Array("username_01", "username_02", "username_03")
RUS = Array("username_01", "username_02", "username_03")

Set oDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
oDic.comparemode = vbTextCompare

oDic("GEN") = GEN
oDic("POL") = POL
oDic("B2B") = B2B
oDic("RUS") = RUS
```

Then you can call your function as follows...

```
IsInArray(auser, oDic(res_group_txt))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the answer is 'yes', you can access these arrays by name. You'd use the `CallByName()` function which enables you to access any property (and, indeed, method) of an object by its name, passed as a string.

The small adjustment you'd need to make to your code would be to create an object which contained the arrays as properties. Specifically, you'd do this by inserting a `Class` object (Insert > Class Module). In the example below, I've called the class *cArrayFields* and added your code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public GEN As Variant
Public POL As Variant
Public B2B As Variant
Public RUS As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    GEN = Array("username_01", "username_02", "username_03", "username_04")
    POL = Array("username_02", "username_03", "username_04")
    B2B = Array("username_03", "username_04")
    RUS = Array("username_04")
End Sub
```

In your main procedure (the one in your module), your code would simply be:

```
Dim o As cArrayFields
Dim targetShape As Shape
Dim targetName As String, shapeText As String, aUser As String
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Long


targetName = "MyShape"
aUser = "username_03" 'test example

Set o = New cArrayFields
For i = 1 To 4
    Set targetShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(targetName)
    shapeText = targetShape.TextEffect.Text
    arr = CallByName(o, shapeText, VbGet)
    Debug.Print IsInArray(aUser, arr)
Next
```

However, I wonder if your users and responsibilities are structured in the most efficient manner. A more intuitive way to go might be to have a list of users and each member contains a list of the areas they are responsible for. If you did it this way, then the look-up would be far simpler; for example you could just use a `Collection` object, which accesses each item by a `String` key. So your code could just be a couple of small routines to create the lists:

```
Private Sub DefineUserList()
    Set mUsers = New Collection

    AddNewUser "username_01", "GEN"
    AddNewUser "username_02", "GEN", "POL"
    AddNewUser "username_03", "GEN", "POL", "B2B"
    AddNewUser "username_04", "GEN", "POL", "B2B", "RUS"
End Sub
Private Sub AddNewUser(userName, ParamArray respAreas() As Variant)
    Dim resp As Collection
    Dim v As Variant

    Set resp = New Collection
    For Each v In respAreas
        resp.Add True, CStr(v)
    Next
    mUsers.Add resp, userName

End Sub
```

And then your look-up routines in your main module as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private mUsers As Collection

Public Sub Main()
    Dim targetShape As Shape
    Dim targetName As String, shapeText As String, aUser As String
    Dim i As Long


    DefineUserList

    targetName = "MyShape"
    aUser = "username_03" 'test example

    For i = 1 To 4
        Set targetShape = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(targetName)
        shapeText = targetShape.TextEffect.Text
        Debug.Print IsUsersArea(aUser, shapeText)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function IsUsersArea(userName As String, respArea As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsUsersArea = mUsers(userName).Item(respArea)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```